# How to immoderately return on build error by Power Shell visual studio build script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, compilation

I have following script for building several projects one by one. But this scripts keeps running even if there is an error. I would like to immediately stop the script and notify the ures that there is a compiler error for one of the project failed to build. Even if possible to notify exactly what is failed to compile. Please suggest me how to do it?

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$build 
)

function buildSas
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $path,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool] $clean = $false
    )
    process
    {
        $msBuildExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe';
        if(-not (Test-Path $msBuildExe))
        {
            Write-Host "MSBuild 15 is not installed, please install MSBuild 15 to use this build script." -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
            exit;  
        }

        if ($clean) {
            Write-Host "Cleaning $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
            & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" /t:Clean /m:4
        }

        Write-Host "Building $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
        & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" /t:Rebuild /m:4 /p:BuildInParallel=true  
    }
}

function buildVs
{
    Write-Host "Building all visual studio projects only." -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor White;
    buildSas .\proj1.sln 
    buildSas .\proj2.sln
    buildSas .\proj3.sln
    buildSas .\proj4.sln
    # many project in list
    Write-Host "visual studio projects build done." -ForegroundColor Magenta -BackgroundColor White;
}

if($build -eq "vs")
{
    buildVs;
    return;
}

buildVs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if msbuild.exe returns different exit codes I'd add function to start msbuild using Start-Process. Something like:

```
$SuccessReturnCode=@(0,3010)
$ProcesTimeOut=3000
$buildparam="$($path) /t:Rebuild /m:4 /p:BuildInParallel=true"

Write-Log -message "Invoking: $myProcess $myArgs, process time-out:$ProcTimeOut seconds"
$process = (Start-Process -FilePath $msBuildExe  -windowstyle Hidden -ArgumentList $buildparam -PassThru)

    Try {
        $process | Wait-Process -Timeout $ProcTimeOut -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Log -message "Completed with return code: $($process.ExitCode)"
            if ($SuccessReturnCode -notcontains $process.ExitCode) {
                Write-Log -level 'error' -message 'something went wrong'
                exit 255

            }

    }
    Catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Log -level 'error' -message "The error message was: <$($ErrorMessage)>"
        $pwid=$process.Id.ToString()
        taskkill.exe /PID $pwid /T /F
    }
```

Comment: will definitely try this as soon as I get some time. Now extremely busy.

Comment: I tied and got error as: Write-Log : The term 'Write-Log' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was in
cluded, verify that the path is correct and try again. I'm trying in PS version 5

Comment: remove or comment-out Write-Log lines - this is my custom log function.

Comment: Exception at line  $process | Wait-Process -Timeout $ProcTimeOut -ErrorAction Stop. Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Timeout'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: I have these variables  $path = '.\DataBackup\DataBackup.sln';
$buildparam="$($path) /t:Rebuild /m:4 /p:BuildInParallel=true"
$msBuildExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe';

Comment: change var name:
     $process | Wait-Process -Timeout $ProcesTimeOut -ErrorAction Stop
ProcesTimeOut insted of ProcTimeOut